# change the value of the button of the button clicked

Tags: jquery

On inserting the new `<li>`, I have to set the value of the button clicked to Delete. How can I do that?

With the actual code, it`s working only once, and on adding other list, the button no more has the the value 'Delete'.

```
$("#mylist :button").click( function() { 
    var text = $(this).val(); 

    if (text == "Delete") { 
        $(this).parent().remove(); 
    } else { 
        $(this).val("Delete"); 
    }
});

$("#mylist li:last-child").live('click', function() { 
    $(this).parent().append('<li>' + '<input type = "textbox">' + 
        '<input type = "button" value= "Save">' + '</li>');
});

<div>
    <ul id="mylist">
        <li id="1">1<button id="Button3">Delete</button> </li> 
        <li id="2">2<button id="Button2">Delete</button></li> 
        <li id="3">3<button id="another_entry">Save</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I reformatted the code snippet for easier reading.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265913/change-the-value-of-the-button-of-the-button-clicked

Comment: @jeerose Perhaps you pasted the wrong URL? You linked to this question (2265913).

Answer (score 3):

Use `text()` instead of `val()`

```
var text = $(this).text();
if (text === "Delete") 
{
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
else
{
    $(this).text("Delete");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. These are often misused:

`.val()` get/set the value of an input

`.text()` get/set the text of an element (e.g 'text' in the following `<td>text</td>`(

`.html()` add HTML inside an element, e.g. `<a>anchor</a>` in the following `<td><a>anchor</a></td>`

Comment: `.html()` does not "add", it "sets".

Answer (score 1):

I think your id selector is wrong

It should be

```
$("#mylist li:last-child button")
```

instead of

```
$("#categorylist li:last-child button")
```

and change

```
$(this).parent().append('...);
```

to

```
$(this).parent().parent().append('...');
```

Comment: If you find yourself using parent().parent() its time to switch to closest().